# Why i have an error if i could create the channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a discord bot with a ticket sistem and this appeared when i reacted the emoji but y could make the channel, i don`t know why this appeared but y have other problems in the code when y do "-close"
This is the output when i react:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robot\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\robot\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\Bot-BillCipher\main.py", line 116, in on_raw_reaction_add
    message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
  File "C:\Users\robot\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1132, in fetch_message
    data = await self._state.http.get_message(channel.id, id)
  File "C:\Users\robot\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

And this is the code of the discord bot:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member.id != bot.user.id and str(
            payload.emoji) == u"\U0001F3AB":
        msg_id = 900132144389705738
        channel_id = 856691291203043398
        category_id = 875749620846850079

        if payload.message_id == msg_id:
            guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

            for category in guild.categories:
                if category.id == category_id:
                    break

            channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)

            ticket_channel = await category.create_text_channel(
                f"ticket-{payload.member.discriminator}",
                topic=f"Ticket creado por {payload.member.display_name}.",
                permission_synced=True)
            await ticket_channel.set_permissions(payload.member,
                                                 read_messages=True,
                                                 send_messages=True)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
            await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, payload.member)

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"¡Tu ticket fue creado!", description=f""" Hey *{payload.member.name}*, escribe **'-close'** para cerrar tu ticket.""", color=PURPLE)
            await ticket_channel.send(embed=embed)
            msg1 = await ticket_channel.send(payload.member.mention)
            msg2 = await ticket_channel.send("<@&897256130944843778>")
            await msg1.delete(delay=0.5)
            await msg2.delete(delay=0.5)
            

            for channel in category.channels:
              if channel.name == "ticket-" + payload.member.discriminator:
                channels = [("ticket-" + payload.member.discriminator) in channel.name for channel in category.channels]
                lenchannels = channels.count(True)
                if lenchannels > 1:
                  await ticket_channel.delete()
                  await payload.member.send("No puedes crear más de un ticket.")

            message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
            await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, payload.member)

            try:
                await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.channel == ticket_channel and m.content == "-close", timeout=3600)

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ticket_channel.delete()
            else:
              await ticket_channel.delete()
```

Answer (score -1):

I already found the error, I had missed putting "message." Here's the corrected line:

```
'message = await message.channel.fetch_message(msg_id)'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).